# Make custom Publisher run on a different DispatchQueue on Swift Combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I created a function that returns a custom Publisher in Swift Combine using the code below:

```swift
func customPubliher() -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
    return Future<Bool, Never> { promise in
        promise(.success(true))
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Then I subscribed to this publisher using the following code:

```swift
customPublisher()
    .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global())
    .map { _ in
        print(Thread.isMainThread)
    }
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in }, receiveValue: { value in
        // Do something with the value received
    }).store(in: &disposables)
```

But even though I added the line `.subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global())` when I do the subscription, the code is **not** executed in a different queue (the `print` in the `.map` outputs true).

However, if I replace my custom publisher for one of built-in Combine publishers, for example `Just()` (see below), the same code is executed fine on a different queue:

```swift
Just(true)
    .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global())
    .map { _ in
        print(Thread.isMainThread)
    }
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in }, receiveValue: { value in
        // Do something with the value received
    }).store(in: &disposables)
```

The `.map` on the code above outputs false.

What am I doing wrong when I use my custom publisher? I want it to run on a different queue, exactly like the `Just()` publisher does.

Comment: your code works as expected in playgrounds

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my test of your code I'm getting `false`. Actually `DispatchQueue` has no one-to-one relation with some specific thread, it is a queue of execution and specifying `DispatchQueue.global()` you ask system to select *some free queue* to execute your task with *default priority*. So it is up to system to decide on which queue and in which thread to execute your task.

If you intentionally want to force it into background, then use

```
.subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it.

However, I find interesting that when I was using `DispatchQueue.global()` the code in my custom publisher seems to be always executed on the main thread, but when I used `Just()` it seems to be always executed in a background thread. Anyway, I'm using the correct queue now.

Answer (score 0):

To run code on the different thread, I believe it can use `.receive(on:)` to make the publisher run on the different thread

```
customPublisher()
.receive(on: DispatchQueue.global())
.map { _ in
    print(Thread.isMainThread)
}
.sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in }, receiveValue: { value in
    // Do something with the value received
}).store(in: &disposables)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try use Deferred

```
func customPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
   Deferred {
      return Future<Bool, Never> { promise in
         promise(.success(true))
      }
   }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```